# Is it possible to save party analysis at lichess.org

Tags: scala, lichess

Is it possible to save party analysis at lichess.org?
Let me describe the scenario: my son uses lichess analysis board to analyse his parties played above, also it allows to "convert" hand-written parties to PGN files.

It would be very helpful if it was possible to save particular analysis right at lichess.org to have a cloud "library" of all parties he ever played and at also it would allow to share parties with his chess coach easily.

Perhaps this feature already implemented under some other sections of lichess, but I did not manage to find it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for Lichess Study: https://lichess.org/study

More info:

- https://lichess.org/blog/V0KrLSkAAMo3hsi4/study-chess-the-lichess-way
- https://lichess.org/blog/Wsdc0C4AAIwAH4_L/lichess-study-and-our-favorite-user-created-content